# Using Javascript in webview

Tags: javascript, android, authentication, webview

So, reading around i read that i could "inject" javascript into a loaded webpage to programatically fill a website's form, so i tried the following:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView WebView;
    WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    WebView.loadUrl("http://www.kingsage.es");
    String username = "XXX";
    String Password = "YYY";
    WebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('login_player').value='"+username+"';javascript:document.getElementById('login_passwd').value = '"+Password+"';");
}
```

However, when i run this on the emulator i get an error as if the website could not be found. if i turn off the second loadUrl method i load the website, but i need to fill the login form programatically!, i figure i am doing something wrong but i haven't found and answer reading around. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: does it even show the website to begin with? www.google.com try it and see if it does show up.

Answer (score 6):

you need to wait until the webpage is loaded (use [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)) then execute your javascript

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished (WebView webView, String url)
   {
         webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('login_player').value='"+username+"';javascript:document.getElementById('login_passwd').value = '"+Password+"';");
   }
});
```

make also sure that you execute only once, not on every [onPageFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) Event

Comment: need help ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249207/android-webview-auto-sign-in

Answer (score 1):

I like JeanLuc's suggestion and it worked for me 98% of the way.  I still needed to automatically log the user into the web page once their username and password had been entered so I did the following and its worked well, except for trying to remove the "do you want to remember the password' message.

```
@Override
            public void onPageFinished (WebView webView, String url)
            {
                  webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('Login1_UserName').value='"+userName+"';javascript:document.getElementById('Login1_Password').value = '"+password+"';");
                  webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('Login1_LoginButton').click();");
            }
```

The second line selected the 'login' button and logged them in automatically.  Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: can i apply the same code on a website that i do not own ?? need urgent reply...because i am having issues

Comment: this code is for a web site I dont have any control over.  So if I have understood your question then the answer is Yes.

Comment: i just replaced some values and implemented in my on page finished but does not do what i want...i think i shud post another question

Comment: here is the link for my question please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249207/android-webview-auto-sign-in

Comment: Sorry unable to as I ended up dropping the javascript idea and asked the web site admin folk to allow a url with params.  I can only offer that solution and I dont believe its going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I acheived it in my scenario where I had to browse a page, fill text boxes and submit.

```
WebView webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webEspView);
webView.SetWebViewClient(new Client());
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.LoadUrl("http://192.168.4.1")
```

Then added the Client class and overloaded onPageFinished() method.

```
public class Client : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        string ssid = Variables.GetInitialUsername();        
        ssid = ssid.Trim(new char[] {'\"'});
        string pass = Variables.GetInitialPassword();   

        var script = $"document.getElementById(\"clientId\").value = \"{ssid}\";" +
                     $"document.getElementById(\"branchId\").value = \"{pass}\";" +                        
                     "document.querySelector('button[type=\"submit\"]').click()";           
        view.LoadUrl($"javascript: {script}");


    }
}
```

Hope it helps.