# Android WebView Auto Sign In

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Following is the code which is I am implementing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webTask);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
    else webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('user_id').value='" + new String ("xxx")+ "';javascript:document.getElementById('password').value = '" + new String("xxx") + "';");


        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

But nothing happens infact web view turns blank and shows text written on its left corner "xxx"

Please help. already searched 3 to 4 hours and of no avail

Comment: try `javascript:document.getElementById('user_id').value='" + new String ("xxx")+ "';document.getElementById('password').value = '" + new String("xxx") + "';`

Comment: Nope facing the same issue ! please help i am tired now by searching for ths

Comment: try `javascript:alert('check me');` and tell me if the alert shown or not

Comment: done that url just loads normally in the webview...no alert is shown

Comment: try delete `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method

Comment: deleted shouldOverrideUrlLoading...absolutely nothing happend ! :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93009/discussion-between-juni-and-randyka-yudhistira).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i have solved the problem. the javascript was not being run because my targeted sdk was >= **KITKAT**.

So, in order to avoid the problem you have to use `webView.evaluateJavascript(yourScript,null);` for devices running on API level 19 or above.

**Sample Code**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
{
    webView.evaluateJavascript(yourScript,null);
}
else
{
    webView.loadUrl(yourScript);
}
```